# SimpleInjector Unbind/Rebind

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have a core set of libraries that are delivered and work "out of the box". Meaning that the services are all wired up inside. I would like to have the ability to modify the core library (without modifying the library itself).

With that said, is there an Unbind/Rebind support in SimpleInjector? I didn't see any publicly visible methods on the container. I did find a private dictionary of registrations that I can get to with reflection.

Does anyone see a reason why I can't remove items from this private dictionary (to then re-add) at runtime with reflection? Is there a method I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removal of registrations is not possible. Overriding registrations however is. You will have to flag the container to allow this:

```cs
var container = new Container();

container.Register<IService, FirstService>();

container.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations = true;

// Replaces the former registration
container.Register<IService, AnotherService>();
```

Comment: container.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations = false again? that way, users will get errors for accidental duplicate registrations.

Comment: Allowing to override any existing registrations is an easy way to allow misconfigurations to get noticed. Prevent usage if possible, and if usage is required, enable it for the shortest possible period of time to prevent any errors. For instance, prevent enabling this option directly after creating the container.

Comment: Exactly. I only want skilled gunman to be able to shoot themselves in the foot.